# Inline Custom Form in Django

Tags: django, forms, view, inline, models

I am trying to create a system to add applications (named `Candidatura` in `models.py`) to a database and, in each application, the user can add as many experiences (named `CandidaturaExp` in `models.py`) as they wish (one to many relation).

I already have `forms.py` and `views.py` working for the application but I have no idea how to do it so a the user can insert experiences. I also have no idea how to create a "PLUS" button in my template to add the experience form since I am not an expert in Java Script.

So, I have the following:

models.py

```
class Candidatura(models.Model):
    ## IDENTIFICACAO E  CONTACTO
    nome=models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Nome Completo')
    nacionalidade=models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Nacionalidade')
    data_nascimento=models.DateField(verbose_name='Data de Nascimento')
    residencia=models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Residência')
    localidade=models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Localidade')
    cod_postal=models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Código Postal')
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254, verbose_name='Email')
    telefone=models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Telefone')

    ## HABILITACAO E CONHECIMENTOS
    nivel_academico=models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Nível Académico')
    ano_conclusao=models.CharField(max_length=4, verbose_name='Ano de Conclusão')
    curso=models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Curso')
    instituicao=models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Instituição')
    outras_hab=models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Outras Habilitações')
    conhec_tec=models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Conhecimentos Técnicos')

    ## DOCUMENTOS ANEXOS
    cv=models.FileField(upload_to=None, max_length=100, verbose_name='Curriculum Vitae', null=True, blank=True) 
    data_criado=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False, verbose_name='Data de criação')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nome

    ## EXPERIENCIA PROFISSIONAL
class CandidaturaExp(models.Model):
    candidatura = models.ForeignKey(Candidatura)    
    experiencia=models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Experiência Profissional')
    ano_admissao=models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Ano de Admissão')
    ano_saida=models.CharField(max_length=4,null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Ano de Saída')
    empresa=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200, verbose_name='Empresa')
    funcao=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255, verbose_name='Função Desempenhada')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.candidatura

class CandidaturaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Candidatura
        fields = '__all__'

class CandidaturaExpForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CandidaturaExp
        fields = '__all__'
```

forms.py

```
class NovaCandidatura(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Candidatura
        fields = ('__all__')

class NovaCandidaturaExp(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:
        model = CandidaturaExp
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def inicio(request):
    return render_to_response('indexDB.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@login_required    
def listing(request):
    table = CandidaturaTable(Candidatura.objects.all())
    return render(request, "listDB.html", {'table': table})

@login_required
def newform(request, template_name="NovaCandidatura.html"):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NovaCandidatura(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            url = urlresolvers.reverse('change_success')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = NovaCandidatura()
    page_title = ('Update user data')
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: What I want is the equivalent for the admin form for the "Add another XX".
I can't seem to do it by myself and I wanted to use a custom template. Not the predefined.